# C# - Custom Environment Variable in Publish Profile

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We are using ***.Net Core 3.1*** and we have multiple publish profiles. In each there is

```
<EnvironmentName>Development</EnvironmentName>
```

or Production etc. I would like to add another variable which is named by me.

Comment: And what are you asking about? Have you tried something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not register any other environment variables when you publish, only the EnvironmentName.

The same thing can be achieved like

```
dotnet publish -c Debug -r win-x64 /p:EnvironmentName=Development
```

if you want to clear out your csproj file.

Coming back to environment variables, I can see two solutions:

1. Move to a docker solution and pass the environment variables into your container. That is pretty easy and straight forward. [Link to docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)
2. Add a powershell script that will set the variables in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the environment variable in your publish profile. You can name it anything you want. To set other variables you would have to use [web.config transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-7.0).